# python 3.6 "Max retries exceeded with url"

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am using requests to signIn server and I get the error below:

> [2018-01-12 11:56:43,931] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='XX.XX.XX.XX', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /public-api/sign-in (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

I searched on stackoverflow and Google. And I tried many methods:

1. set keep_alive = False
2. set Header: Coonection = 'close'
3. add retry and sleep.
4. restart server and client.

The error is still the same.

Can anybody help?

I am using Python 3.6.3. And the script is used in airflow.

Code is below:

```
    import requests
    from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
    from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
    s = requests.Session()
    retry = Retry(connect = 5, backoff_factor = 1)
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries = retry)
    s.mount('http://', adapter)
    s.keep_alive = False
    res = s.post(self.conn.host + '/sign-in', data = json.dumps({
        'name': "XXX",
        'pwd': "XXX"
    }))
    response = res.json()
```

Comment: Try the request with curl and see if it works. Or try it with httpbin. There's nothing here to suggest requests is working incorrectly.

Comment: If you're getting "connection refused", there's nothing about your request that can influence that except the host and the port. That happens at the socket level. Seconding "try it with curl", but my bet would be it won't work, and you've got either the host or the port wrong, or there's some firewalling going on.

Comment: I tried curl and solved it. It fail when I curl on that machine but succeed on other machine.

Answer (score 0):

The Airflow API probably has a rate limit as the [Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limits) has one.

Comment: its not true i started a sanic in my localhost and making one request per seccond it gives this error some times